# Laravel Feature Test but data doesnt appear until after a request

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm having troubles with feature tests and data seeming to both exist and not exist depending on where and when that data is being retrieved from.

My test only seems to work if I run them one at a time but if run them all together using `php artisan test` then there seems to be no data so the test fails

This is my class:

```php
<?php


namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\AssetGroup;
use Throwable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class AssetGroupTest extends CoreFeatureTest
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->seed();
        $this->logMeIn();
    }
    
        public function testAssetGroupShow(): void
    {
        $response = $this->get('/api/asset-group?keyBy=none');

        $response->assertStatus(200);

    }

    public function testAssetGroupDelete(): void
    {
        $assetGroup = AssetGroup::whereHas('user', function ($query) {
            $query->where('user_id', 1);
        })->first();

        $response = $this->delete('/api/asset-group/' . $assetGroup->uuid);

        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $this->assertSoftDeleted($assetGroup);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you put `$this->logMeIn();` inside every test?

Comment: This sadly doesn't change the core problem.I have had to switch to DatabaseMigrations which is incredibly slow and doesn't really solve the initial problem